# Use from `$.each` in several times separate.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, each

After search and click on result search and click on plus(button add input) next to input "INSERT VALUE HERE" in the example, in new input `$('.auto_complete').keyup(function () { ...` not work.

I believe that have to bind the events separately and use a **closure** so that each element has its own set of variables(or **change the logic** so that only use the value in the field and don't need any state variables),

how is it?

EXAMPLE: [see here](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

Js full code: http://jsfiddle.net/6yPxn/

$.each:

```
var ac = $(this).text();
var ok = $.grep(data, function (e) {
    return e.name == ac;
})[0].units;
$.each(ok, function (bu, key) {
    //alert(key.name_units);
    $("<div class='mediumCell'/>").hide().fadeIn('slow').append('<b>' + key.name_units + '</b>', $('<div class="column" style="float: left;" />')).appendTo(".list_units");
});
```

Comment: Your question is way unclear, try to solve the issues one by one, if you have a working block, then build on it. Indent your code, you are going to be from know-it-all to nightmares with the above kind of code. You just can't grasp the workflow if you are starting out on it without indentation.

Comment: you see the [example](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign) and search value `salam` in field "INSERT VALUE HERE" and clicking on result it now next to this field is a plus(button add input) that you click on it plus, in new field not work `$.each` (resulet search). why?

Comment: I just can't follow your code. There is lots of it going on there, if you can manage to create a stripped down small sample of your case, then probably we can help. I doubt anyone would take a bite on this one, the way it is right now.

Comment: Your full JS code is incomprehensible. If you cannot isolate the specific problem in your code and show only that, your're not abstracting your code very well. Please learn how to properly organise and abstract your javascript code.

Comment: you can see in above post my revised in code as simple. is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs fine, but I don't see anywhere in that code you've provided where you're adding an event handler to the input box.

The issue is in http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/files/js/admin.js, somewhere around the top:

```
$('.auto_complete').bind('keyup',function () {
 /* ... */
});
```

When the page loads it binds several event handlers to input boxes and the like. When you create a new one this functionality is *not* added unless you're using jQuery's [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or something similar. As the documentation notes:

> This method [`.live()`] is a variation on the basic `.bind()` method for attaching event handlers to elements. When `.bind()` is called, the elements that the jQuery object refers to get the handler attached; elements that get introduced later do not, so they would require another `.bind()` call.

I don't really want to wade through all the nested `click` and `delegate` and `bind` calls, but I guarantee you that's where your problem lies. To fix it you'll probably need to have either the autocomplete section run on your newly created node, use `.live` instead, or just [`.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the original.

Comment: i use `.live` instead `.bind`, there are result search in new input but after click on result search, there is problem. !? see you: [EXAMPLE](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

Comment: @RC your code in new input after search value, not have result search. !?

Comment: I changed from `$('.auto_complete').bind('keyup',function () {` to `$('.auto_complete').live('keyup',function () {`, and search in new input"INSERT VALUE HERE" have result but after click on result search it there is problem in show output in following same new input. see you: [EXAMPLE](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)